# Why are MySQL user priviledges exported with backslashes?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I use a mixture of phpMyAdmin and the command line to maintain user privileges.  When I went to export some user privileges using phpMyAdmin the sql it produced was

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `table\_name`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

I don't understand why the backslash was added to the table name.  I read somewhere that the underscore is used as a wildcard?  If I was to run that sql but remove the backslash would the user permissions be the same as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the permissions won't be the same. You're correct, `_` is used as a wildcard, it stands for one arbitrary character, another wildcard would be `%`, which stands for zero or more characters
(the analogous regex patterns would be `.` and `.*`).

These wildcards applied to permissions work the same as in [string comparisions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html), so if you remove the backslash the underscore is not treated as literal anymore and therefore the granted permissions apply to all databases* matching the pattern.

*Note: although it's called `table_name` here, it's actually refering to a database and not a table.